# In R, how can I change the location of row and column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this raw dataset and the below is sample dataset :

```
 X1         X2
 1      Born 1946-05-27
 2  bioguide    A000370
 3      Born 1979-06-19
 4  bioguide    A000371
 5      Born 1980-04-18
 6  bioguide    A000367
 7      Born 1958-06-12
 8  bioguide    A000369
 9      Born 1948-03-23
 10 bioguide    B001291
```

Using this, my desired output is below:

```
       Born        biouguide
1     1946-05-27     A000370
2     1979-06-19     A000371
3     1980-04-18     A000367
4     1958-06-12     A000369
5     1980-04-18     A000367
```

Also, the below is dput of raw dataset:

```
structure(list(X1 = c("Born", "bioguide", "Born", "bioguide", 
"Born", "bioguide", "Born", "bioguide", "Born", "bioguide"), 
    X2 = c("1946-05-27", "A000370", "1979-06-19", "A000371", 
    "1980-04-18", "A000367", "1958-06-12", "A000369", "1948-03-23", 
    "B001291")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Could you please help me make the desired output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(X1) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = X1, values_from = X2) %>%
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Born       bioguide
#  <chr>      <chr>   
#1 1946-05-27 A000370 
#2 1979-06-19 A000371 
#3 1980-04-18 A000367 
#4 1958-06-12 A000369 
#5 1948-03-23 B001291
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
unstack(df1, X2 ~ X1)
```

Comment: did not know the `unstack ` function, impressive.

Answer (score 8):

One `base R` option could be:

```
data.frame(Born = df[c(TRUE, FALSE), 2],
           biouguide = df[c(FALSE, TRUE), 2])

        Born biouguide
1 1946-05-27   A000370
2 1979-06-19   A000371
3 1980-04-18   A000367
4 1958-06-12   A000369
5 1948-03-23   B001291
```

Comment: A bit restrictive but clever

Answer (score 3):

With data.table you can dcast with rowid(X1) as the rows, X1 as the column names, and X2 as the values, then remove the rowid(X1) row after.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

dcast(df, rowid(X1) ~ X1, value.var = 'X2')[, -1]

#          Born bioguide
# 1: 1946-05-27  A000370
# 2: 1979-06-19  A000371
# 3: 1980-04-18  A000367
# 4: 1958-06-12  A000369
# 5: 1948-03-23  B001291
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution

```
dfout <- `names<-`(data.frame(matrix(df$X2,ncol = 2,byrow = T)),unique(df$X1))
```

such that

```
> dfout
        Born bioguide
1 1946-05-27  A000370
2 1979-06-19  A000371
3 1980-04-18  A000367
4 1958-06-12  A000369
5 1948-03-23  B001291
```